# swiftUI: .sheet uiimagepicker search bar disappears

Tags: swift, swiftui

I use the ImagePicker example from HWS. If I run this code on a real device and tap the search bar the .sheet disappears.

Do you have any hints for me?

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    var mode:UIView.ContentMode?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {}
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
        
 func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: what search bar? Where is the sheet? What is the question?

Comment: the error is about the implemented search bar in UIImagePicker. As I described the UIImagePicker disappears if you try to insert text. I've found some questions about it in the internet, but no real solution...

Comment: where is this `UIImagePicker` with the search bar in your code?

Comment: Hi working dog, the attached code is the whole code. the search bar comes with the  UIImagePicker by Apple. I don't have to implement it additional.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. Getting the same issue on ios 15.